# CPLEX MIP current node LP relaxation

Tags: c, cplex

During a MIP optimization with CPLEX C APIs is it possible to retrieve the linear relaxation (dual variables, reduced costs, etc ...) of the current node (i.e. every n nodes)?

I've registered a callback function (CPXsetsolvecallbackfunc) in order to be notified each time a new node is available. In the callback I use CPXgetcallbackinfo to retrieve the node information and CPXgetcallbacknodelp to retrieve the linear relaxation but unfortunately the procedure CPXsolution returns that no solution exists and the MIP optimization exits.

Here is a sample code realized starting from an [IBM example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400065) where environment and problem are assumed to be properly initialized.

```
struct noderange {
int startnode;
int endnode;
 };
typedef struct noderange NODERANGE;

NODERANGE     nodeswritten;
nodeswritten.startnode = -1;
nodeswritten.endnode = 2100000000;

status = CPXsetsolvecallbackfunc(environment, usersolve, &nodeswritten);
if(status) {goto TERMINATE;} 

status = CPXmipopt(environment, problem);
if(status) {goto TERMINATE;}
```

where the usersolve procedure is

```
static int CPXPUBLIC usersolve(CPXCENVptr env, void *cbdata, int wherefrom, void *cbhandle, int *useraction_p) {

int       status = 0;
int       nodecount;
static    int count = 0;
CPXLPptr  nodelp;
NODERANGE *nodeswritten;

*useraction_p = CPX_CALLBACK_DEFAULT;
nodeswritten = (NODERANGE *)cbhandle;

/* Find out what node is being processed */

status = CPXgetcallbackinfo(env, cbdata, wherefrom, CPX_CALLBACK_INFO_NODE_COUNT, &nodecount);
if (status)  goto TERMINATE;

if (nodecount >= nodeswritten->startnode && nodecount <= nodeswritten->endnode) {

    /* Get pointer to LP subproblem, then write a SAV file. */

    status = CPXgetcallbacknodelp(env, cbdata, wherefrom, &nodelp);
    if (status)  goto TERMINATE;

    int rows = CPXgetnumcols(env, nodelp);
    int cols = CPXgetnumrows(env, nodelp);

    int lpstat;
    double objval;
    double* x = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * CPXgetnumcols(env, nodelp));
    double* dj = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * CPXgetnumcols(env, nodelp));

    double* pi = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * CPXgetnumrows(env, nodelp));
    double* slack = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * CPXgetnumrows(env, nodelp));

    status = CPXsolution(env, nodelp, &lpstat, &objval, x, pi, slack, dj);
    printf("Solutionstatus = %d\n", lpstat);

    if (status) { goto TERMINATE; } // <--- HERE it returns no solution exists

    free(x);
    free(dj);
    free(pi);
    free(slack);

    printf("[%d]\trows = %d cols = %d\t sol stat = %d\t z = %f\n", nodecount, rows, cols, lpstat, objval);



    if (nodecount == nodeswritten->endnode)  status = 1;
    count++;
}


TERMINATE:
return (status);

}
```

Comment: So many things wrong with your post...no code, no actual explanations, we don't even know if you bothered to try anything before posting.

Comment: You're very right, I'm updating the post with more detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, the callback is called *before* the subproblem has been solved so CPXsolution returns that no solution exists.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.